# I need to automatically start a non GUI application through a terminal line because I don't have a GUI

Tags: command-line, server, cron, autostart

I have a proxmox ubuntu container running ubuntu 23.10 and becuase it is a container it doesn't allow me to use a GUI. I need to run a server application as soon as the container boots up incase it gets shut down or something. I have tried the gnome services but that doesn't work because proxmox won't allow me to add a montior to a container, I have tried to put it in as a service, that didn't work, I have tried the /etc/rc.local. It needs to run without me signing in because it's on a server so I may not always be there to start it. Is there a way to set up a cron job, if so, how. It needs sudo permissions though because I need it to be able to keep everything up to date. Please note, I am pretty new to the linux command line and so may be doing something, if not everything, wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a line in the root crontab like this

`@reboot your-script-here`

and `your-script-here` will get started at boot.

To edit the root crontab, use the command

`sudo crontab -e`